# how to add a class to window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class to the link being called through JS onload in body tag . for example

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'http://example.com/'; class='blank'; ">
```

Any idea how to do this?

I am sorry if I have been unclear about the requirement. I need this to work as I want to target a function of a jquery that works on click with a class .

thank you

Comment: Can you explain the purpose, for this, as this question is unclear.

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://example.com/'` doesn't create a link it is JS that will be executed so you can't add a class because there is no `<a>` element. You can add a class to the `<body>` element though